# Why do I get a segmentation fault if I print the contents of this memory location

Tags: c, memory, pointers

Suppose I do the following

`int *p = 1;
printf("%d", *p);`

I get a segfault. Now, as I understand it, this memory location 1 is in the address space of my program. Why should there be a problem in reading this memory location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operating system won't let you access memory locations that don't belong to your program. It would work on kernel mode though...

Comment: I thought each process has its own virtual address space. So starting from 0x0, all space is my process's and I should be able to access it ?

Comment: @AnkurVj: All virtual space is yours, but you still need to allocate it first to be a valid location.

Comment: Suppose I declare an integer and print its address. Is that location the real physical memory location?

Comment: @AnkurVj: Its a logical address, one that was allocated with the system.

Answer (score 4):

Your pointer doesn't point to anything valid. All you do is assign the value `1` to a pointer-to-int, but `1` isn't a valid memory location.

The only valid way to obtain an pointer value is either take the address-of a variable or call an allocation function:

```
int a;
int * p1 = &a; // OK
int * p2 = malloc(sizeof(int));  // also OK

*p1 = 2;
*p2 = 3;
```

As for "why there should be a problem": As far as the language is concerned, if you dereference an invalid pointer, you have undefined behaviour, so anything can happen -- this is really the only sensible way to specify the language if you don't want to introduce any arbitrary restrictions, and C is all about being easy-to-implement.

Practically, modern operating systems will usually have a clever virtual memory manager that needs to request memory when and as needed, and if the memory at address `1` isn't on a committed page yet, you'll actually get an error from the OS. If you try a pointer value near some actual address, you might not get an error (until you overstep the page boundary, perhaps).

Answer (score 3):

To answer this properly will really depend upon a number of factors.  However, it is quite likely that the address 0x00000001 (page 0) is not mapped and/or read protected.

Typically, addresses in the page 0 range are disallowed from a user application for one reason or another.  Even in kernel space (depending upon the processor), addresses in page 0 are often protected and require that the page be both mapped and access enabled.

EDIT:
Another possible reason is that it could be segfaulting is that integer access is not aligned.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that mapping page 0 is not even allowed on secure operating systems (it can lead to exploits against the kernel).

Answer (score 2):

No, address 1 is not in the address space of your program. You are trying to access a segment you do not own and receive segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to print 1, not the memory location. 1 isn't a valid memory location. To print the actual memory location do:

```
printf("%p", p);
```

Note the %p as icktoofay pointed out.

Comment: I believe the correct formatting specification for a pointer is `%p`, not `%d`.

Comment: No. I am not trying to print the memory location. I am indeed trying to print what is stored at that memory location

Comment: I think he's actually trying to output the `int` *at address 1*.